# CATransaction : How to Cancel?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer, catransaction

I have following transaction on a **CALayer**:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
 self.myLayer.opacity = 1
CATransaction.commit()
```

Since the **transaction** goes on for two seconds, there are moments where I have to cancel/pause.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code -

```
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
```

You can temporarily disable layer actions when changing layer property values by setting the value of the `transaction’s` `CATransactionDisableActions` to `true`

Comment: I't doesn't actually cancels animations which are already running.

Comment: @kelin I try to cancel using above method, but it will not cancel it. Can you please tel me for what it will used for.

Comment: @Sudhirkumar, no I can't, I have the same problem as you :-D